# unable to display the skeleton from react-loading-skeleton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am fetching data from youtube data Api which I mapped through the fetch data and displayed it on my screen,i also have a keyword variable which is storing an array of different words so that when a user clicked on any of these words it fetches the data and pour it on the screen. while trying fetching... data I want to display up to 20 lists of skeleton's shadows on the screen while isLoading which if false at the initial state turns to true and while waiting for that data is being fetched but I am having some difficulty displaying that on my screen. Please I will really appreciate it if anyone can help out. Please i have stuck in this for days now

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import SearchFeed from './SearchFeed';
import GroupsBar from './GroupsBar';
import { fetchVideos } from '../redux/extraReducer';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import numeral from "numeral";
import request from "../redux/request";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import "./styling/styling.css"
import { fetchNextPage } from "../redux/videoReducer";
import SkeletonVideo from "./skeleton/SkeletonVideo";

const VideoDetail = ({ groupHandler }) => {
  const [views, setViews] = useState("");
  const [timing, setTiming] = useState("");
  const [channelIcons, setChannelIcons] = useState({});
  const [allVideos, setAllVideos] = useState([]);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state)=> state.user.youtube?.isLoading)
  console.log(`this is ${isLoading}`)

  const videos = useSelector((state) => state.user.youtube.obj);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchVideos())
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [dispatch]);

   const fetchData = (()=>{
    dispatch(fetchVideos())

   })



  useEffect(() => {
    if (videos && videos.items && videos.items.length > 0) {
      setAllVideos((prevVideos) => [...prevVideos, ...videos.items]);
    }
  }, [videos]);
  
  





   useEffect(() => {
    if (videos && videos.items && videos.items.length > 0) {
      const videoIds = videos.items.map((video) => video.id);
  
      const getVideoDetails = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await request("/videos", {
            params: {
              part: "contentDetails,statistics",
              id: videoIds.join(","),
            },
          });
  
          console.log("API Response:", data); // Log the API response
  
          if (data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
            const { contentDetails, statistics } = data.items[0];
            console.log("Content Details:", contentDetails); // Log the contentDetails 
            console.log("Statistics:", statistics); // Log the statistics property
            setTiming(contentDetails?.duration || "");
            setViews(statistics?.viewCount || "");
          } else {
            console.log("No items found in the API response.");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching video details:", error);
        }
      };
  
      getVideoDetails();
    }
  }, [videos]);
  

    enter code here





        // Set channel icons
       const icons = {};
        data.items.forEach((item) => {
          icons[item.id] = item.snippet.thumbnails.default;
        });
        setChannelIcons(icons);
      };

      getChannelData();
    }
  }, [videos]);

  return (
    <>    
  
    <Container>
      <h2>Recommended</h2>
      <GroupsBar groupHandler={groupHandler} />
      <VideoBox>

   

        {
          
      
          allVideos
          .map((video) => {
           
            const {
              id,
              snippet: {
                channelId,
                channelTitle,
                title,
                publishedAt,
                thumbnails: { medium },
              },
            } = video;
            const isVideoLoading = isLoading && !video.id;

            const seconds = moment.duration(timing).asSeconds();
            const duration = moment.utc(seconds * 1000).format("mm:ss");

            return (
           
   
           <div>    
              <VideoContain>
               { isVideoLoading ?(

             <span> { [...Array(20).fill()].map((_, index)=>{
              return(
                <SkeletonVideo/>
              )
                
              

             })} </span>
               ) :



              
               (
                <>  
            
                <SearchFeed video={video} id={id} channelId={channelId} />

               
               <VideoData>  

                {medium && <img src={medium.url} alt="" />}
                
                
                <p  >{duration}</p>
                </VideoData>   
               
                <AvatarPhoto>  
               
               
                  <img src={channelIcons[channelId]?.url} alt="" />
                  <h5>{title}</h5>
                  </AvatarPhoto>

                  <DataIcon>
                  <p>{channelTitle}</p>

                  </DataIcon>

                <TitleData>  
               
                
                <span>{numeral(views).format("0.a")}  views  </span>
               
                <span>{moment(publishedAt).fromNow()}</span>
                </TitleData>

             
              

    


            
         
          </>
           )}
              </VideoContain>
              </div>
              
             
            
         
            );
          })}
       
      </VideoBox>
    
    </Container>
  
 
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoDetail;


The SkeletonVideo.js

const SkeletonVideo = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', margin: '1rem 0', zIndex:"300px", position:"relative" }}>
      <SkeletonTheme color="#232b2340" highlightColor="#26282b">
        <Skeleton height={180} />
        <div>
          <Skeleton style={{ margin: '0.5rem' }} circle height={40} width={40} />
          <Skeleton height={40} width="75%" />
        </div>
      </SkeletonTheme>
    </div>
  );
};



export default SkeletonVideo
```